# What to do about undeleting this deleted question (10K only)?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

So, today this question was asked: [Can the Warforged Integrated Weapon Trait be Disarmed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154969/can-the-warforged-integrated-weapon-trait-be-disarmed)

It appears to be about some 3rd party homebrew content from [dndguide.com](https://dndguide.com/races/Warforged). It was closed as unclear, then reopened, NautArch answered with basically "we can't answer that because it's 3rd party and only that 3rd party can answer it" (which is a perfectly valid answer, my issue isn't with the answer; in fact, it's probably the only answer this question *can* have bar the author of the 3rd party content joining RPG.SE and answering), and... then the OP deletes the question.

**Currently it's sitting on 1 undelete vote - should it be undeleted?**

Should we:

- respect the OP's intentions to delete their own question (meaning we should leave it deleted); or
- it's a valid question and it's now belongs to RPG.SE, so if we want it, we can undelete it despite OP's wishes to have it deleted (meaning we should undelete it)?

I'm not sure I like the 2nd option (or maybe that's just because of the way I worded it), but the undelete vote makes me question that...

Comment: PS: Anyone tempted to vote to reopen it, obviously I have no power nor should I have power over your right to vote, but I'd prefer if we have some consensus or at least favourably received answers claiming that it should be undeleted before doing so. My intention isn't to bring more attention to the question itself, thereby increasing it's likelihood of being undeleted, although what ultimately happens to it once the dust settles on my meta question, I'm not so bothered about...

Comment: Update: It's aliiiive! (and undeleted)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### In this case, the question should be undeleted

Full disclosure: I cast the undelete vote mentioned on the question (before seeing this meta post). My reasoning was following the [help section on deleting questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question), namely the following part:

> If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

The question in this case actually got a good answer (in my opinion, I would upvote if I could) but the asker deleted the question before upvotes on the answer were possible: a mere 1 minute after the answer was posted.

I think this is a decent enough on-topic question that actually got a good answer and is useful to have on the site as other people that come across that same 3rd party resource might have the same question. The question was also sitting on a positive score (admittedly a mere +2/-1) so presumably two other people found the question useful.

I don't really see a valid reason for deletion in this case, the question is not [completely useless to the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/404165) so considering the presence of a good answer I think this question should not have been deleted.

Comment: This makes sense to me, and just to clarify that I did ask the question after your undelete vote, since it was seeing the vote that made me wonder. I agree with your reasoning though (and would have also voted on NautArch's answer had I been able to).

Answer (score 2):

## Undelete it

Please see this [relevant meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/should-we-permit-undeleting-questions-against-the-author-s-will), which indicate that content once posted nominally belongs to the site, and that high rep users can vote to undelete much as they can vote to delete.

Comment: It's already stated that the high-rep users *can* vote to undelete it. But should they? Why? What would be the benefit?

Comment: @MikeQ - That one has answers from CM team members, but browsing through many of the undelete related material [such as this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106619/when-is-it-ok-to-vote-to-undelete-posts-that-were-deleted-by-their-owners), there is very little consensus on undeleting questions.

Comment: Right. I should've been more specific. Why should users vote to undelete this particular question?

Comment: @MikeQ - Ah, I see. Less of a policy thing and more of a "Why this question? Why now?" kind of thing. Grok.